# Nodejs REST without express

Tags: web-services, node.js, rest

All the tutorials I see for creating rest apis use express. While I'm sure this is a fine solution, I would like something with less overhead and as few dependency modules as possible. What are some alternative solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try some alternative projects like Hapi.js http://spumko.github.io/ or Restify http://mcavage.github.io/node-restify/

They are focused on REST API development.

I know there is much more choices if you want to compare

Comment: These both look like good solutions. restify might be a little more what I am looking for but Hapi seems easier to work with. I'll test out both tonight

Comment: If you want to add some tests as well, I used Frisby.js http://frisbyjs.com/. Which is really great for that. Unfortunately the project is less maintained currently